# Get parent of child element with xpath in Symfony2 Crawler

Tags: php, xpath, domcrawler

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href='#'>First Item</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Second Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

I can access all links via xpath query.

```
    $result = $crawler->filterXPath('//ul[@id="menu"]/li/a');
```

but i wonder if is it possible to access parent element of child element using filterXPath() method without editing xpath query in PHP DomCrawler ?

For example i want to access **//ul[@id="menu"]** using node element in each() method.

```
$result = $crawler->filterXPath('//ul[@id="menu"]/li/a');
if($result->count() < 1){
  exit('Query not found.');
}
$result->each(function (Crawler $node)){
    $parentOfNode = $node->parent() // ??
    //...
};
```

Comment: Your XPath doesn't correspond to the HTML snippet posted. Maybe you meant `//ul[@id="menu"]/li/a`?

Comment: How about [`$node->parents()`](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_parents)?

Comment: $node->parents() gives me parent node list but i want to access get html content of parent element.